# CQRS with REST APIs

Tags: node.js, rest, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am building a REST service over CQRS using EventSourcing to distribute changes to my domain across services. I have the REST service up and running, with a POST endpoint for creating the initial model and then a series of PATCH endpoints to change the model. Each end-point has a command associated with it that the client sends as a `Content-Type` parameter. For example, `Content-Type=application/json;domain-command=create-project`. I have the following end-points for creating a Project record on my task/project management service.

- **api.foo.com/project**

  - **Verb:** POST
  - **Command:** create-project
  - **What it does:** Inserts a new model in the event store with some default values set
- **api.foo.com/project/{projectId}**

  - **Verb:** PATCH
  - **Command:** rename-project
  - **What it does:** Inserts a `project-renamed` event into the event store with the new project name.
- **api.foo.com/project/{projectId}**

  - **Verb:** PATCH
  - **Command:** reschedule-project
  - **What it does:** Inserts a `project-rescheduled` event into the event store with the new project due date.
- **api.foo.com/project/{projectId}**

  - **Verb:** PATCH
  - **Command:** set-project-status
  - **What it does:** Inserts a `project-status-changed` event into the event store with the new project status (Active, Planning, Archived etc).
- **api.foo.com/project/{projectId}**

  - **Verb:** DELETE
  - **Command:** delete-project
  - **What it does:** Inserts a `project-deleted` event into the event store

Traditionally in a REST service you would offer a PUT endpoint so the record could be replaced. I'm not sure how that works in the event-sourcing + CQRS pattern. Would I only ever use POST and PATCH verbs?

I was concerned I was to granular and that every field didn't need a command associated with it. A PUT endpoint could be used to replace pieces. My concern though was that the event store would get out of sync so I just stuck with PATCH endpoints. Is this level of granularity typical? For a model with [6 properties on it](https://github.com/FocusMark/api-project/blob/development/src/shared/project-model.js#L8) I have [5 commands](https://github.com/FocusMark/api-project/blob/development/src/commands/command-factory.js#L16) to adjust the properties of the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would I only ever use POST and PATCH verbs?

Most of the time, you would use POST.

PUT, and PATCH are defined with remote authoring semantics - they are methods used to copy new representations of a resource from the client to the server.  For example, the client `GET`s a representation of `/project/12345`, makes local edits, and then uses `PUT` to request that the server accept the client's new representation of the resource as its own.

PATCH, semantically, is a similar exchange of messages - the difference being that instead of sending the full representation of the resource, the client returns a "patch-document" that the server can apply to its copy to make the changes.

Now, technically, the PATCH documentation does put any restrictions on what a "patch-document" is.  In order for PATCH to be more useful that POST, however, we need patch document formats that are general purpose and widely recognized (for instance, `application/merge-patch+json` or `application/json-patch+json`).

And that's not really the use case you have here, where you are defining command messages that are specific to your domain.

Furthermore, remote authoring semantics don't align very well with "domain modeling" (which is part of the heritage of CQRS).  When we're modeling a domain, we normally give the domain model the authority to decide how to integrate new information with what the server already knows.  PUT and PATCH semantics are more like what you would use to write information into an anemic data store.

On the other hand, [it is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.” -- Fielding, 2009

It may help to recall that REST is the architectural style of the world wide web, and the only unsafe method supported by html is POST.

So replacing your PATCH commands with POST, and you're on the right path.

[Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/paper-tigers-and-hidden-dragons)

> I should also note that the above is not yet fully RESTful, at least how I use the term. All I have done is described the service interfaces, which is no more than any RPC. In order to make it RESTful, I would need to add hypertext to introduce and define the service, describe how to perform the mapping using forms and/or link templates, and provide code to combine the visualizations in useful ways. I could even go further and define these relationships as a standard, much like Atom has standardized a normal set of HTTP relationships with expected semantics

The same holds here - we aren't yet at "REST", but we have improved things by choosing standardized methods that are better aligned with our intended semantics.

One final note -- you should probably replace your use of DELETE with POST as well.  DELETE is potentially a problem for two reasons -- the semantics aren't what you want, and the standard delete payload has [no defined semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)

Expressed another way: DELETE is from the [transferring documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain, not from *your* domain.  A DELETE message sent to your resources should be understood to mean the same thing as a DELETE message sent to any other resource is understood.  That's the uniform interface constraint at work: we all agree that the HTTP method tokens mean the same thing *everywhere*.

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect -- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)

As before: remote authoring semantics are not obviously a good fit for sending messages to a domain model.

Comment: Thanks - this was really informative. I think I'll go back to a non-CQRS implementation to simplify things. My domain isn't that complicated. For microservice architectures though would you still use some form of event sourcing or notification to avoid microservices calling each other all the time for data they might need? A task app for instance, would need to delete tasks & note records when a user is deleted. Would my account service ping a webhook my APIs listens on - or would I just publish an event to a serverless function that processes the notification within the individual service?

Comment: Central idea is that two micro services should be able to communicate even if they don't run at the same time.  The common solution to that is for them to communicate by writing/reading messages from a high availability message store.

Answer (score 9):

This is a common question that we get a lot of the time when helping developers getting started with CQRS/ES. We need to acknowledge that applying REST in a pure way is a really bad match for DDD/CQRS since the intention of the commands are not  explicitly expressed in the verbs GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE (even though you *can* use `content-type` like you did). Also the C/R-side of the system are definitely different resources in a CQRS-system which does not match up with REST.

However, to use HTTP to provide an API for a CQRS/ES system is very practical.

We usually only use `POST` for sending commands, to either a `/commands` endpoint or to endpoints with the name of the command, i.e `/commands/create-project`. It's all about how strict you want to be. In this case we embed the command type in the payload or as a content-type.

However, it is all a matter of what matches the tech stack better and what you choose here usually does not make or break the solution. The more important part is usually to create a good domain model and get the whole team onboard with this way of thinking.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

One question that comes to mind is, is REST the right paradigm for CQRS at all?

One completely different way to structure this is to not have action-focused endpoints, but instead structure your REST API as a series of events that you add new events to (with POST).

Events should be immutable and append-only, so maybe a `DELETE` method doesn't make that much sense for mutations.

If you're going all in with CQRS (good luck, I've heard the war stories) I would be inclined to build an API that reflects that model well.

Comment: The only reason I'm using CQRS is because it seems to pair well with event sourcing. I am using event sourcing to keep all of the decoupled serverless micro-services in sync. Is there a different pattern, or examples/docs, you know of that I could use event-sourcing with REST and just exclude CQRS all together? My product doesn't really need CQRS itself and I'm probably over complicating it.

Comment: No I think CQRS and event-sourcing are both major red flags unless your use-case is something that models really well on a ledger, such as accounting systems, version control, etc. This is way off topic though =). I've built event sourced systems, but these were for stock/option trading ledgers so it was a good fit. My understanding is that for most other applications developers end up regretting this. If it's the first time you're hearing this, I would recommend doing some more digging.

Answer (score 1):

This Google Cloud article [API design: Understanding gRPC, OpenAPI and REST and when to use them](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/api-management/understanding-grpc-openapi-and-rest-and-when-to-use-them) clarifies the REST vs RPC debate. REST is more relevant for entity-centric API whereas RPC is more relevant for action-centric API (and CQRS). The most mature [REST level 3](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3) with hypermedia controls works well only for entities with simple state models.

Understand and evaluate first the benefits of REST for your case. Many APIs are REST-ish and not RESTful. [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/) is actually RPC mapped over and HTTP endpoints but it doesn't prevent it to be widely adopted.